# How to get mocha to output test failures without transpiled line codes?

Tags: mocha.js, babeljs, babel-register

```
1) test "before all" hook:
 (SystemJS) ToMyIds is not a function
    TypeError: ToMyIds is not a function
        at execute (C:/Users/cpatton/Documents/myApp/client/app/view/map/map.jsx!transpiled:59:50)
    Error loading C:/Users/cpatton/Documents/myApp/client/app/view/enhancers/to-my-ids.jsx
```

Currently all my mocha test failures are being outputted with the transpiled line/column numbers. Is there a handy way I can get mocha using my sourcemaps?

Here's my current testing entry point:

```
require('systemjs');
require('./jspm.config');
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');

const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const Mocha = require('mocha');
const glob = require('glob');
const mocha = new Mocha();
const sinon = require('sinon');

// Bug Fix <?>: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/58#issuecomment-162514956
global.document = jsdom.jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
global.XMLHttpRequest = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();

glob('@(app|test)/**/*.spec.js?(x)', (err, files) => {
  let file;
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  for (let i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    file = files[i];
    mocha.addFile(file);
  }
  mocha.ui('bdd');
  mocha.timeout(0);
  // mocha.reporter('min'); // My personal preference for debugging
  return mocha.run((failures) => {
    return process.exit(failures);
  });
});
```

I believe this is different than [Babel + Mocha stack traces report wrong line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238428/babel-mocha-stack-traces-report-wrong-line-number) because the stack trace actually includes it's transpilation step as can be seen by the *!transpiled* and retainLines does nothing if included:

```
require('babel-register')({
  retainLines: true,
});
```

Comment: The answer on the other question mentions the `source-map-support` module, which you are not using. You *need* to use this module to have any support for sourcemaps in Node.

Comment: @Louis That module is already included and installed by requiring [babel-register](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/fce92fa1adb69f0de5ec642448441b9314fb4441/packages/babel-register/src/node.js#L15) in my test runner above.

Comment: I've reopened. You should investigate whether the issue originates from using jsdom, and tag the question accordingly. I have some test suites that use jsdom. Using jsdom does throw a monkey wrench into the whole thing. A couple days ago I tried to get better stack traces and tried to use `source-map-support` with jsdom but it did not work. However, the version of jsdom I'm using is a couple majors behind the latest and I cannot upgrade so I don't know whether upgrading to the latest would have solved the problem.